# Understanding an embedded C language variable declaration

Tags: c, variables, embedded, declaration

I'm trying to understand some embedded C code that declares a variable.

```
uint8_t *p=(uint8_t *)&NOCAN_REGS;
```

The NOCAN_REGS is a structure defined in a different file (see link below)

My understanding is that the variable "p" is a pointer to an unsigned 8 bit integer, but everything from the typecast after the equals sign is a mystery to me.

I would appreciate a step by step explanation, or a link to a learning resource that can help me master this syntax.

- https://github.com/fastbike/canzero-driver-firmware/blob/master/driver/nocan.h

Comment: If you pick it apart into their own small parts, do you know what each of them mean? Do you know how to initialize a variable on its definition? Do you know about pointers and pointer declarations? Do you know what the *pointer-to* operator `&` does? Do you know what the conversion or *cast* operation `(uint8_t *)` does? If you don't know at least one of these, then I suggest you take a few steps back and refresh the appropriate chapters and sections in your *beginners* books.

Comment: Also please note that the embedded part is mostly a [*red herring*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring). The only part that might related to embedded systems is the variable `NOCAN_REGS` itself, which is probably an variable located to mark some CAN-related registers in memory. Everything else is just standard and plain C.

Comment: Maybe link to the github source file that actually contains the code you are asking about... or better yet include relevant parts of the code here.

Comment: Ok so the code you link to is both flawed and naively written. Is this supposed to use an on-chip CAN controller or an external one? Does it work? I don't see how they make the connection between the sloppy global `NOCAN_REGS` and the actual hardware registers. Is this handled through some external spaghetti programming such as DMA, or is it not handled at all?

Comment: Hmm, If I wanted a critique of the code I would have asked that question. It is external code contained in the github repo (linked in the original question) that I am attempting to understand. Not code I have written, but need to use. Many thanks for your interest.

Comment: @DavidMoorhouse Regardless, I did just post a code review of the nocan.h/nocan.c files. I strongly recommend you to _not_ use this code  - Engineer ethics mean I can't let **ithub publish things like this uncontested or someone might actually end up using it. My background is 20+ years of professional embedded systems development, including lots of experience of CAN drivers and CAN stacks in particular.

Comment: @Lundin, thanks for the detailed follow up. At this stage we have inherited this code base, but take notice of the need for a thorough review and probable rewrite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, here is everything after the `=` sign:

```
(uint8_t *)&NOCAN_REGS;
```

Taken from right to left (because it's easier to explain in that order):

```
NOCAN_REGS;
```

... this is the name of a global struct-object, as you mentioned.

```
&
```

The `&` sign indicates you want a pointer-to-whatever-is-after-it, so

```
&NOCAN_REGS
```

... means "pointer to the NOCAN_REGS struct".

```
(uint8_t *)
```

The cast is here to forcibly change the type of the expression from `nocan_registers_t *` to `uint8_t *`.  That is, you are telling the compiler that you want the expression's type to be pointer-to-unsigned-bytes, rather than a pointer-to-a-`nocan_registers_t`.

Typically a programmer would do a cast like this when he wants to treat a struct's memory as if it were a raw byte-buffer.  It's a tricky thing to do, since when you throw away the type-information like that, issues that the compiler normally takes care of for you (like the endian-ness of member-variables, their alignment to appropriate boundaries, padding bytes, etc) now become things the programmer has to think about... but it can be useful in cases where you want to e.g. dump the raw memory to disk or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, simplified. Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: The code you link to is very flawed and amateurishly-written with many bugs and bad practices.

Since it mentions SPI, it would appear that the purpose is to control an old external CAN controller like MCP2515 etc using SPI. (Please note that most engineers stopped using these external CAN controllers long before Cortex M and STM32 were even invented.)

To explain what the code does and the problems I could spot only at a glance:

- `NOCAN_REGS` is apparently a struct corresponding to the memory map of the registers in an external CAN controller accessed over SPI. This struct has two oddities: packing was disabled and one member is `volatile` qualified.

  If this had been an on-chip CAN controller then the whole of it would have to be `volatile`. In this case `volatile` only serves as protection against compiler optimizations when the variable is shared with an ISR. So it's correct but should perhaps be documented better.

  What's worse is the disabled packing, which means that the `uint32_t` members are likely allocated at misaligned addresses. So accessing them as `uint32_t` might cause hard faults. Not sexy. These should have been `uint8_t [4]` arrays. (Or alternatively padding should not have been disabled and the struct should be serialized/deseriazlied on member-by-member basis.)
- `NOCAN_REGS` is declared as global variable and exposed to the entirely program, which is very bad practice. It should have been declared `static`. It should not be in the header. No other part of the program but the driver should access it, if the program design was sound.
- The `uint8_t *p=(uint8_t *)&NOCAN_REGS;` etc casts are used for the purpose of *serialization* - turning a larger type into a byte stream. Most SPI communication and external CAN controllers work with bytes. By taking the address of the struct `&NOCAN_REGS` and converting it to a pointer to `uint8_t`, we can access the struct byte by byte. So it's handy for passing on a struct to the SPI hardware.

  Normally casts like this would be deeply problematic in C, but there is a special rule (ISO C 6.3.2.3) which allows us to inspect any type in C using a pointer to a character type. On all sound mainstream systems, `uint8_t` is just a typedef for `unsigned char` so it is a character type. Meaning that the cast is valid and de-referencing the struct byte by byte is also valid. (The opposite - going from an array of character types to a struct, by using a struct pointer, is not allowed/undefined behavior.)
- Examples of such undefined behavior are the casts  `(uint16_t*)CHIP_UDID`,  `(uint16_t*)NOCAN_REGS.UDID`. Anything can happen here, it could lead to misaligned access and strict aliasing violation bugs. Never write dirty casts like these.
- The macros `NOCAN_STATUS_SET` should set off all alarms and blinking red lights during code review. You *do not* write drivers for a specific hardware peripheral that handle re-entancy to an ISR by disabling the global IRQ mask. This will trash all timing and behavior of any other unrelated interrupt present on the MCU. I've lost count over how many times such rotten driver code have caused problems. These should *only* disable the specific interrupt for the CAN and/or SPI peripheral, not shoot the whole MCU timing to pieces each time the struct variable is accessed.
- Please note that CPU endianess (STM32 is little endian) vs CAN controller endianess may be an issue here. I don't know which controller that's used, but one has to have this in mind during serialization. CAN overall has a tendency to favour big endian and the CAN data link layer uses big endian (identifier, CRC).
- `~D` etc on a 16 bit type while executing on a 32 bit MCU isn't correct. Hello integer promotion: the result of `~0x5476` will *not* become 0xAB89 but `0xFFFFAB89`. Which is then treated as a *negative* number dec -21623. The whole `pseudo_hash` is plain sloppily written by someone who seemingly didn't grasp integer promotions in C - if it works at all it is because of luck.

Overall I would strongly recommend not to use this code. It needs to be reviewed more in-depth than my brief review above, and this needs to be done by someone with at least intermediate embedded C/microcontroller programming skills. After that, it might be possible to salvage the code, but at a bare minimum, the misalignment and global IRQ bugs must be fixed.

Comment: Also in case gcc is used, make sure to use `-ffreestanding -fno-strict-aliasing`. Otherwise the strict aliasing bugs need to be fixed too, because gcc historically is _not_ trustworthy when it comes to strict aliasing violations. More conventional embedded systems compilers tend to not abuse strict aliasing optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. The code is using the onboard CAN controller and driving a MCP2562 CAN transceiver. The SPI communication is with an upstream SAMD21 application mcu.

Comment: @DavidMoorhouse What's "onboard", on chip or on PCB? I don't see how this code could work with an on-chip controller because `NOCAN_REGS` is not memory mapped to the register address nor is it `volatile`. It just a variable in RAM with no connection to any hardware register at all. Similarly if this was a DMA buffer then it would have to be volatile too. And since when does STM32 use 8 bit registers... Also, serializing on-chip registers is senseless. As is including the SPI driver from the CAN driver.

Comment: @DavidMoorhouse It would appear that the actual can driver is can.h/can.c. So this is something else, mucking around with some registers unrelated to the actual CAN controller.

Comment: Thx, I'll take a look in the weekend. You have been a big help. This coding is new to me (background is 20+ years of Windows programming), so the C and embedded stuff is a great challenge.<br> Currently following through a YT tutorial of setting up a STM32Fxx toolchain in Linux :) So on a steep learning curve and you have provided useful pointers (no pun intended).

Comment: @DavidMoorhouse You are welcome, but please note that I've just taken a brief glance at a single code file without understanding the context. It does look quite brief for a CAN driver, since those are usually some 2k+ LoC, on-chip or external. And well, many of the issues here are universal: misalignment, strict aliasing violations, integer promotion - these would be bugs in Windows too.